# How to do URL rewriting in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, mod-rewrite, sinatra

I want to redirect all these kind of requests

```
 http://www.example.com/2013/01/my-sample-post/feed
 or 
 http://www.example.com/2013/01/my-sample-post/feed/
```

to

```
 http://www.example.com/2013/01/my-sample-post/
```

I am using sinatra and [rack--rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) gem.

```
  rewrite %r{/*/feed?}, '/$1'  // not working..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a dot in the regex. You also need a capture group with `()` around the wildcard, so it should be `(.*)` between the slashes. Iguess you are also missing a slash at the end.  This should work:

```
rewrite %r{/(.*)/feed/?}, '/$1'
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: then why do you need the question mark at the end?

Comment: Then you need `%r{/(.*)/feed/?}`, not `%r{/(.*)/feed?}`. The latter will match `/fee` and `/feed` but not `/feed/`. The `?` is not a wildcard, but a quantifier it means "one or none" of the previous expression (single character `d` in this case). Same thing with `*` - "zero or more of the" and also `+` - "one or more"